# Assign string to variable in R

Tags: r

I have a list of variables

```
l <- list(1,2,3)
```

From which I am extracting each variable using

```
list2env(setNames(l,paste0("var",seq_along(l))), envir = parent.frame())
```

which creates `var1`, `var2`, `var3`.

Now I need to pass to a function

```
list(var1, var2, var3)
```

How can I do that dynamically? For example if the list is

```
l <- list(1,2,3,4)
```

I don't want to change my code to

```
list(var1, var2, var3, var4)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the final result you want?  I'm a bit confused by what you mean by "variables" in the first sentence.

Comment: I would give serious consideration as to whether you shouldn't just keep these items in a list in the first place. One of the great things about working with objects in lists is that you don't need to take them out and put them back in. Anything you can do with an object that isn't in a list can be done with an object that is, plus you preserve the ability to iterate directly over its members and don't have lots of rubbish polluting your workspace.

Comment: Thanks, the answer above is what I was looking for. I know this is not ideal, but I need to adapt to existing (and non-modifiable) input and output functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
l <- list(1,2,3,4)
list2env(setNames(l,paste0("var",seq_along(l))), envir = parent.frame()) 
List <- mget(ls(pattern = 'var'))
```